# Integration by parts of $\frac{\ln(1+\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: integration

(i) Use the substitution $u=\sqrt{x}$ to show that

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x}} dx = 2-\ln4$$

(ii) Use integration by parts to show that

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}} dx = ln16 -2$$

Note: Parameter of integral is 1 AND 0

Part(ii) i reached $2/3\ln2 + 1/6\ln2 -1/6$

I must use the formula

UV - $\int Vdu/dx $

How do i get the answer $\ln16 -2$?

Comment: Do you mean that these should be $\int_0^1$?

Comment: Yes please,thanks

Comment: Can you write how you get wrong answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}} \,dx = 2\int_0^1 \ln(\  \underbrace{1+\sqrt{x}}_u\  ) \left(\ \underbrace{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\,dx}_{du}\ \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & 2 \int_1^2 \ln u \, du = \underbrace{2\int w \, du = 2wu-2\int u\,dw}_{\text{integration by parts}} = 2u\ln u - 2\int u \frac{du}u \\[15pt]
= {} & 2u\ln u - 2\int du = \cdots\cdots
\end{align}

Comment: Have you use integration by parts ?? sorry am new..

Answer (score 1):

for (ii) we obtain
$\int \frac{\ln(1+\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}dx=2\ln(1+\sqrt{x})(1+\sqrt{x})-2(1+\sqrt{x})+C$
Sonnhard.

Comment: Edit your post to add the second answer and refrain from signing your name on answers.

Answer (score 0):

for (i) we have
$u=\sqrt{x}$ thus we get $x=u^2$ and $dx=2udu$ thus our integral is
$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{2u}{1+u}du$
Sonnhard.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=(1+\sqrt{x})$, then note that $\int ln(u)dx = u\ln(u)-u$